# Prove that if $r^2$ is irrational then $r$ is irrational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

> Consider the statement
>
> “*For all real numbers $r$, if $r^2$ is irrational then r is irrational.*”
>
> Prove the statement by contraposition. Prove the statement by contradiction.

So I'm preparing for an exam in Discrete math, I came up across this question and can't seem to get the answer. I've tried using the formulas  but I don't know how to get the answer.

Comment: The contraposed is : "if $r$ is *rational*, then $r^2$ is *rational*".

Comment: What (exactly) have you tried? Show, don't tell.

Comment: Start applying the def of *rational* to $r$.

Answer (score 3):

Contraposition means you reverse the implication and negate both ends of it, so the sought result is that if $r$ is rational so is $r^2$, and this is trivial viz. $(a/b)^2=(a^2)/(b^2)$.